# Error Installing Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I have tried several times to install Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization. Anytime I try, I get this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       An item with the same key has already been added.           0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "install"?

Comment: Which other install apart from nuget install.